# Simulating mousedown-mousemove-mouseup(Select two paragraphs) events using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select text from two paragraphs and then perform some action.
For example,

```
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<p>Para 3</p>
<p>Para 4</p>
```

Now I want to select 'Para 2' and 'Para 3' so that I can copy or delete this text.

I need to automate this as I do manually by performing mouse down at start of 'Para 2' then mouse move and then mouse up at end of 'Para 3'

Answer (score 0):

what about if you get all elements with the "p" tag and then get the text of those that you want. Something like:

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.tagName("p"));
String str = elems.get(1).getText();
str += elems.get(2).getText();
```

Comment: This won't help when I try to copy content from different divs all together. For example, if I have to select a paragraph and then an image and table and then copy these div and paste somewhere else in my online editor.